# How to set border bottom to cover width of text rather than whole hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

I have some css code which displays a border line under a nav menu link if hovered over or selected. The thing is that in desktop it looks good as you can see here:

Desktop:

[image]

The issue is on mobile. If you look at the picture below, the border line goes all the way across the menu. Would be good if it just covers the text/icon only. Does anyone know how to fix this using css?

Mobile:

[image]

CSS:

```
#{$wrap} { 
    clear: both; 
}

a.mega-menu-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1034a6 !important;
}

.mega-current-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Example html:

```
 <a class="mega-menu-link" href="..." tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `a.mega-menu-link` element is too wide. So instead what I suggest you do is either put all your navigation links, even if only the one you want underlined, inside a smaller `<div>` element with the desired width and then set that border-bottom as desired.